# What is the meaning of the saying full of beans and vinegar?

Tags: expressions

Where did the saying full of beans and vinegar come from and what does it mean?

Comment: I've never heard of it. What does it mean? Where did you read it? Can I find it in an online dictionary for instance? (hint, hint)

Comment: "Full of beans" I have heard.  If I say you are full of beans it means I think you are lying.  That the statement you just made is false.

Comment: @GEdgar I thought to be "full of beans" was to be full of energy, full of life. Maybe I'm thinking of "jumping beans"....? So "full of beans" is a euphemism for "full of BS"?

Comment: See here https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+full+of+beans ... nut no mention of vinegar.  Is the "vinegar" just a one-time enhanced version by somebody?

Comment: In Britain it does mean full of energy (because beans are supposed to make horses lively).

Answer (score 7):

This appears to be a compound of two expressions having a similar meaning.
"Full of beans" and "Piss and vinegar" both mean full of energy and life, although to my ear the second expression carries a particular sense of the energy tinged with aggression, while the first expression does not.
[The Phrase Finder](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/piss-and-vinegar.html) defines "Piss and Vinegar" as:

> Rowdy, boisterous, full of youthful energy.

while the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-full-of-beans) defines "Full of beans" as:

> to have a lot of energy and enthusiasm

tagging it as 'UK informal'.

Comment: In my experience, here in the US, "full of beans" means the person is lying, same as calling "BS!" or "you're full of shit!"

Comment: Emphasis on "compound" I think.